# Spring Boot Zuul API Gateway returning a 404 response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I am attempting to setup Spring Boot Zuul 2.2 so that I can send requests to a service that is registered to Eureka and thus known to Zuul.

I can access the Swagger UI of the service via Zuul, but when I attempt to send a request to the service I get a `404 HTTP status - not found` response.

The service is configured like so:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
```

The Zuul application is configured like so:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
spring:
  application:
    name: app-zuul
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: routes,filters
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
```

and finally, the Eureka configuration:

```
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
spring:
  application:
    name: app-eureka
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
```

I can send requests directly to the user service via `http://localhost:3335/api/v1/...` but I receive a `404` when I attempt the request `http://localhost:8763/app-user/api/v1/...`.

Am I missing some configuration?

Answer (score -1):

You have to add zuul routes in the zuul server properties:
Eg:

```
zuul:
   routes:
      accounts-web:#app name 
         url: http://localhost:8081 # app url
```

After adding the routes properly, you would be able to access the URL.

Reference: https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/

To use eureka app name in routes, add routes like:

```
zuul:
    routes:
        app-user: #app name
            path: /app-user/** #app-url
        app-user:
            serviceId: APP-USER #eureka serviceID
```

Reference: https://springbootdev.com/2018/02/03/microservices-declare-zuul-routes-with-eureka-serviceid-spring-cloud-zuul-eureka/

Comment: I can't hardcore the url though? The url is known by Eureka?

Comment: Then that should be your question. could you mention what you are exactly looking for. Updated the answer with reference.